# Retrieving data from a secondary table that is joined to the primary one via the primary key in both

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core website that I'm trying to build from an old webforms one. There is currently a one-to-one table relationship where a main `ASPNETUsers` table joins to a POC table via the same Id column in both. I'm new to ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework and trying to figure out how I can get this working in the models and the service.

Here are the two model classes:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Core.Models
{
    [Table("ASPNetUsers")]
    public class UserViewModel
    {
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        public string? MobilePIN { get; set; }
        public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string? PhoneExt { get; set; }

        public POC? POC { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace TRRWSCore.Models
{
    [Table("POC")]
    public class POC
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string? UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual UserViewModel? User { get; set; }

        public string? POCAddress1 { get; set; }
        public string? POCAddress2 { get; set; }
        public string? POCCity { get; set; }
        public string? POCState { get; set; }
        public string? POCZip { get; set; }
        public string? POCTitle { get; set; }
        public string? POCFax { get; set; }
        public bool? ThirdPartyConsultant { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my service I have the following code:

```
UserViewModel = await _context.UserInfoDbSet
                              .Include(p => p.POC.Id == id)
                              .Where(a => a.Id == id)
                              .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

`UserInfoDbSet` is the `DbSet` that is registered with the `UserViewModel` model class. I've also tried just

```
UserViewModel = await _context.UserInfoDbSet
                              .Include(p => p.POC)
                              .Where(a => a.Id == id)
                              .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

but both yield null. When I remove the `.Include` clause, it does actually generate a result, but it doesn't include linked POC data, just the data in the UserViewModel.

How can I get that data inserted as part of the overall results?

Comment: You have a table UserViewModel with an associated class and a table POC with an associated class yet you're pulling a different table from your context (UserInfoDbSet). It should be pulling from UserViewModel in the context: await _context.UserViewModel.Include().Where()...

Comment: The table is actually called ASPNetUsers.  Does the class need to have the same name as the table?  I have a statement above the class name - [Table("ASPNetUsers")], so I thought that might be enough, but do I need to change the name of my model class to ASPNetUsers for Core to understand the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem relies on the fact that `UserViewModel` has declared a FK relationship with `POC`. At the DB level, it would rather be expected we have a column for POC Id, and defined a FK constraint. So had we have something like this:

```
[Table("ASPNetUsers")]
public class UserViewModel
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? MobilePIN { get; set; }
    public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string? PhoneExt { get; set; }

    public string? POCId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("POCId")]
    public virtual POC? POC { get; set; }
}
```

Then the following query would return that you are looking for:

```
UserViewModel = await _context.UserInfoDbSet
                              .Include(p => p.POC)
                              .Where(a => a.Id == id)
                              .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

As a side note, TBH I don't get the fact that `UserId` is nullable on `POC`. Does any `POC` exists without being associated with a `UserId` ? If so, then it's fine. Otherwise, this normally should have been defined as non nullable.

Comment: Good point about the nullable POC.  I've been looking at the data in this POC table and it actually isn't there, so this whole question may be moot.  This application had existed for over 10 years and they have changed the data model a bunch over time, and there are some tables like POC which don't seem to have a purpose.  It seems like rows are being created, but the only content of those rows is the foreign key from the ASPNetUsers table, so I may be able to just scrap the entire table and make things much simpler.  But thanks for the tip, as it will be helpful for similar cases.